# how ko.observable declaration in magento 2 works without mentioning it in any variable?

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, magento2.3.3

In Knockout we make the variable to be observable like `var a=ko.observable();` but in Magento 2 without mentioning ko.observable() the variable acts as an observable variable.

1. This is **customer.js** file and its path is

> *vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/view/customer.js*

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function (Component, customerData) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        /** @inheritdoc */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            this.customer = customerData.get('customer');
        }
    });
});
```

2. This is **header.phtml** file and it's path is

> *vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml*

```
<li class="greet welcome" data-bind="scope: 'customer'">
        <!-- ko if: customer().fullname  -->
        <span class="logged-in"
              data-bind="text: new String('<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Welcome, %1!', '%1')) ?>').replace('%1', customer().fullname)">
        </span>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: customer().fullname  -->
        <span class="not-logged-in"
              data-bind='html:"<?= $block->escapeHtml($welcomeMessage) ?>"'></span>
        <?= $block->getBlockHtml('header.additional') ?>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </li>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "customer": {
                        "component": "Magento_Customer/js/view/customer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

***Question :*** How `this.customer` variable from js file becomes ko.observable and acts in phtml file as `customer()` in `<!--ko-->`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice the line `this.customer = customerData.get('customer')`.

`customerData.get()` returns a `ko.observable({...})`.
If you want to dig deeper, you can look at the `get` function from `Magento_Customer/js/customer-data`.
This one returns `buffer.get(sectionName)` (buffer is a variable defined in the same file).
and `buffer.get`  looks like this:

```
get: function (sectionName) {
    if (!this.data[sectionName]) {
        this.bind(sectionName);
    }
    return this.data[sectionName];
}
```

So when you request a section from the buffer, if that section already exists it is returned, if not, then it is initialized via the `bind` function which looks like this:

```
bind: function (sectionName) {
    this.data[sectionName] = ko.observable({});
}
```

To conclude... when requesting a section from the `customerData` object....

- the first time you request it, it is initialized with `ko.observable({})` and returned
- from the second time forward, it is just returned.

That's why you get an instance of `ko.observable` even if you didn't declare it yourself.